# Understanding Matlab Pattern Recognition Neural Network Plots

Tags: matlab, neural-network, epoch, confusion-matrix

I was currently doing a project on Vehicle classification and it has almost finished now but I have several confusion about the plots I get from my Neural Network

I used 230 images `[90=Hatchbacks,90=Sedans,50=SUVs]` for classification on 80 feature points.
Thus my `vInput` was a `[80x230]` matrix and my `vTarget` was `[3x230]` matrix

Classifier works well but I don't understand these plots or if they are abnormal or not.

**My neural Network**
[image: Neural Network]

Then I clicked these 4 plots in the `PLOT` section and got these sequentially.

**Performance Plot**
[image: Performance]

**Training State**
[image: training state]

**Confusion Plot**
[image: Confusion plot]

**Receiver Operating Characteristic Plot**
[image: ROC plot]

I know the images they are a lots of images but I know nothing about them.
On the matlab documentation they just train the system and plot the graph
So please someone briefly explain them to me or show me some good links to learn them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### First two plots shows training statistscs.

**Performance Plot** shows you mean square error dynamics for all your datasets in logarithmic scale. Training MSE is always decreasing, so its validation and test MSE you should be interested in. Your plot shows a perfect training.

**Training State** shows you some other training statistics.

Gradient is a value of backpropagation gradient on each iteration in logarithmic scale. `5e-7` means that you reached the bottom of the local minimum of your goal function.

Validation fails are iterations when validation MSE increased its value. A lot of fails means owertrainig, but in you case its OK. Matlab automatically stops training after 6 fails in a row.

#### The other two plots shows you the results of your network simulation *after* training.

**Confusion Plot**. In your case its 100% accurate. Green cells represent correct answers and red cells represent all types of incorrect answers.

For example, you may read the first one (training set) as: "59 samples from the class 1 was corrctly classified as class 1, 13 samples from the class 2 was corrctly classified as class 2 and 6 samples from the class 3 was corrctly classified as class 3".

**Receiver Operating Characteristic Plot** shows the same thing, but in a different way - using [ROC curve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Receiver_operating_characteristic):

[image]

Comment: Don't you think this perfect classification may mean I am doing something terribly wrong (I mean there should have been at least 1-2 incorrect classidication while testing/validation/training)..
May be this is because I used 23 images and made 10 replicas of each (at different orientation and shifting).

Comment: The only think that may be wrong with your training is the way you separated your data into 3 datasets. You should guarantee that training and validation samples contains some new information, otherwise you won't be able to correctly test and validate your results.

Comment: Having a lot of replicas of the same image is OK as long as you keep them all in the same dataset. Having the same image in all datasets may affect your trainig.

Comment: The idea of a training set is to check that your network is actually learning to distinguish the type of objects you're showing it and not the exact objects you're using to train it.

Comment: As for your results, 100% accuracy is not too abnormal. I mean, it happens. But your **Performance Plot** looks too perfect: all three datasets behave as one.

Comment: as I mentioned in the question the training dataset was a 2D matrix of `[80x230]` where `80=feature points` and `230=images`.
In them the first 90 images belong to 'class-HatchBack' and then next 90 belong to 'class-Sedan' and the last 50 belong to class 'SUV'.
So Is it the distribution you were refering to in your first comment.

I mean should I try to put them randomly...[it should not matter I think]

Comment: No. To train neural network you need three datasets: training set, test set and validation set. If you have only one then matlab randomly splits it into three. Each set should contain examples from each of your classes. Training set should be the largest one, but test set and validation set should contain some new information, not presented in training set.

Comment: Ohhh!!! The 3 from `classes` got me confused with the 3 from `datasets`...
I was just wondering that if my professor asks me `why are the plots so perfect?` then what am I gonna reply him. :)

Comment: For examle, if you have 9 **different** hatchbacks, then you should keep at least one unique hatchback for testing and one unique hatchback for validation. The same for all your classes.